# undefined variable php laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

i kept getting the same error,

> undefined variable: theaters on my blade, line 14.

here is my **addcine.blade.php line 14**

```
@foreach ($theaters as $theater)
    <option value="{{ $theater->name }}"/>
    @endforeach
```

here is my addcinemacontroller

```
public function index(){

$theaters = Theater::all();

return view('schedules.addcine', compact('name'));
```

and my route

```
Route::get('addcinema','AddCinemaController@index');
});
```

Comment: return view('schedules.addcine', compact('theaters'));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
return view('schedules.addcine', compact('theaters'));
```

`compact('theaters')` does exactly this:

```
return view('schedules.addcine', ['theaters' => $theaters]);
```

Comment: oh. thank you very much. such a silly mistake. forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 2):

```
return view('schedules.addcine', compact('theaters'));
```

you are not sending the `$theaters` value to the view,

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `name` instead of `theaters` in controller

```
public function index(){

$theaters = Theater::all();

return view('schedules.addcine', compact('theaters'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `$thaters` variable to view so that you can use it there.

Return like this:

```
return view('schedules.addcine', compact('theaters'));
```